# Reactor Code SwithIfEmpty and Mono is not working as Expected in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Below is the process I want to achieve in through my code.

When I receive JsonRecord I need to check if it exists in Redis Cache.

I) If record is NOT present:

```
1. Create a record in external system DB using REST call.
2. Create  Cache Record from JsonRecord and response from step1
3. Create the external System using response from step2
```

II) If record is present:

```
1. Update a record in external system DB using REST call.
2. Update the Cache Record from JsonRecord and response from step 1
3. Update the external System using response from step2
```

***NOTE 1: Calls to external systems in step 1 and step 3 are different.***

**Issue1:** When *`transform`()* method in `MessageTransformationHandler` returns null, it directly going back to the **switchIfEmpty** block in **`RecordHandler`**.

Expected: When *`transform`()* method returns null, it should go back to calling method.

**Issue2:** When *`transform`* method in `MessageTransformationHandler` returns null, it directly going back to the switchIfEmpty block in **`RecordHandler`**.

Expected: When *`transform`* method returns null, it should go back to calling method. then from that method to **`flatMap`** condition in **`RecordHandler`** class.

```
@Component
public class RecordHandler {

    @Autowired
    private contentService contentService;

    @Autowired
    private RedisService redisService;

    @Autowired
    private MappingService mappingService;

    public Mono<String> handleMessage(JsonRecord record, String recordId, String , long startTime) {

        try {
                        
            return redisService.getObjectFromRedis(record.getRecordId())
                    .flatMap(redisResponse -> {

                            return contentService.updateEvent(record, redisResponse)
                                    .flatMap(dBResponse -> mappingService.createOrUpdateMappingData(dBResponse, record, redisResponse))
                                    .filter(mappingResponse -> mappingResponse!=null)
                                    .flatMap(mappingResponse -> contentService.storeOrUpdatePrices(record, mappingResponse, requestId));
                            
                        }
                    }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {

                        return contentService.createEvent(record, redisResponse)
                                .flatMap(dBResponse -> mappingService.createOrUpdateMappingData(dBResponse, record , startTime))
                                .filter(mappingResponse -> mappingResponse!=null)
                                .flatMap(mappingResponse -> contentService.storeOrUpdatePrices(record, mappingResponse, requestId));
                    }));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Mono.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class ContentServiceImpl implements ContentService {

    @Override
    public Mono<EventType> updateEvent(JsonRecord record, EventsMapping mappingData) {

        return Mono.just(record).flatMap(record -> {

            MessageTransformationHandler messageHandler = messageTransformationHandlerFactory
                    .getHelper(record.getClassName());

            //transform method can return null value
            ContentManagementModelGeneric payload = messageHandler.transform(record, mappingData);
            
            if (payload == null) {
                return Mono.empty();
            }
            return ContentRESTService.createRecord(record, payload);
        }).flatMap(sportsDBResponse -> Mono.just(getResponseEvent(record, sportsDBResponse)));  
    }
}
```

```
public class MessageTransformationHandler {

    public ContentModel transform(JsonRecord record, MappingData mappingData) {

        ContentModel cm = null;
        List<MarketType> somethingList = record.getSomething().getSomeList_().stream().map(something -> {
            
        //do something and return null.
        return null
        })
        .filter(something -> something != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if(somethingList == null || somethingList.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return cm;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe issue 1 and issue 2 are the same issue

Comment: it's worth noting that `flatMap` does not get invoked for empty monos. From my understanding the code is working as expected.